# Pytest hanging despite timeout

Tags: python, pytest

I've installed [pytest-timeout](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-timeout) and am trying to run a test which looks like this:

```
@pytest.mark.timeout(30)    # Time out after 30 seconds
def test_main(timeline):
    if config['check_rules'] is True and save_only is False:  # If configured to do so:
        for instance in timeline.instances:                   # For each app (in each device) on our timeline...
            RulesGenerator(instance).gentest_rules()
```

As I understand it, the test should time out after 30 seconds. What I observe, however, is that the test hangs indefinitely:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.0.5, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /home/kurt/dev/clones6/ipercron-utils/tester, inifile: 
plugins: timeout-1.2.0, flask-0.10.0
collected 1 items 

tester.py
```

In short, it seems like the `timeout` feature is not working as expected. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the `-s` option to print output, I believe I see what the problem is: the test uses a fixture, `timeline`, which takes a long time to generate. The `timeout` applies only to the test itself, not to the generation of its fixtures.